# Como verificar se a resposta de um servidor retorna (200 OK) em java ?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma app android, e gostaria de verificar se um site ou uma URL esta ativa

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao site StackOverFlow. Para conseguir ajudá-lo, preciso que você explique melhor sua dúvida. Você já tentou fazer seu código? Posso postar o que você já tentou? Assim eu verifico onde está o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verificação pode ser feita utilizando APIs REST próprias do Android, fazendo uma chamada GET a partir de uma URL e esperar uma Response, a partir dessa Response você faz a lógica em cima do Status Code que receber.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit/Response.html

Uma das APIs REST do Android - https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Outra alternativa é o uso da própria API do Java para verificar, mas ficará limitado a API do pacote `java.net`

Ex:

```
public int getStatusCode(String urlPath) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlPath); // http://www.seusite.com.br
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();
        return conn.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vlw, caiu como uma luva!